# Populate Min/Step Qty in Woocommerce Order Add Product Screen

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

In our Woocommerce store the majority of products are sold in minimum or case quantities. When creating orders on the back end, the office staff often enter the incorrect quantity. I would like to populate the product quantity in the 'Add Products' window to reflect the minimum quantity, based on the meta key '_alg_wc_pq_min'. What is the correct hook to access this area?

[image]